# Flat copy directories that match a certain pattern

Tags: gradle

I'm trying to write a task that does flat copy directories and their respective contents to a destination folder named target.

The folders in question have a ".wo" suffix and are sparse across different levels of the directory tree and need to be copied with all their contents

A structure like this...

```
source
├── directoryToCopy1.wo
│   ├── somefile.txt
│   └── somefile2.txt
├── directoryToCopy2.wo
│   └── somefile3.txt
└── subdirectory
    ├── directoryToCopy3.wo
    ├── directoryToCopy4.wo
    │   └── somefile4.txt
    └── subdirectory2
        └── directoryToCopy5.wo
```

should be copied to this

```
target
├── directoryToCopy1.wo
│   ├── somefile.txt
│   └── somefile2.txt
├── directoryToCopy2.wo
│   └── somefile3.txt
├── directoryToCopy3.wo
├── directoryToCopy4.wo
│   └── somefile4.woo
└── directoryToCopy5.wo
```

My current attempt looks like this

```
task copyFolders(type: Copy){
    from (applicationOutputDir) {include 'source/**/*.wo/*'}
    into 'target'
}
```

Unfortunately this task does not copy anything. Any suggestions?

**Edit**

Okay the source directory was not set correctly.
Also I'm using a FileTree now.
Now it looks like this:

```
task copyComponents(type: Copy){
    from fileTree('source').include('**/*.wo/*')
    into (new File(applicationOutputDir,'Contents/Resources'))
}
```

unfortunately I'm not there yet. This task copies the whole directory as it is to the target folder.